# if f is periodic and continuous

Tags: real-analysis

If $f : R  \rightarrow Y $   is periodic and continuous then f is constant or f has a fundamental period
Could you give me some suggestions to prove this?

Comment: Prove that if $f$ does not have a fundamental period, then $f^{-1}f(0)$ is dense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no fundamental period, then there is some sequence $x_n$ which converges to $0$ such that $f(x + x_n) = f(x)$ for all $x$. Since $x_n$ can be made arbitrarily small, show that there is a dense set of real numbers with the same value, by taking translates by these arbitrarily small periods. A continuous function is determined by its values on a dense set, so being constant on this dense set means being constant on all of $\mathbb{R}$.